# Running application unit test inside a Docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I have started to use docker recently and I containerised a python application. I used the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.6.5

# working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy requirement file to working directory
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "./run.py"]
```

I have some unit test which I invoke using pytest. I was thinking how I can include this in the docker container such that unit tests would run inside a docker container. Should I build a different image for it. What are your recommendations on it.

Comment: I'd recommend [multi-staged](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) builds with a "test" stage that installs the dependencies for and executes your tests. Ref. this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59643123/1423507) meh, I use `docker` for everything (tests included) - not everyone has `python` / `python3` installed but in a pinch anyone can execute the tests using `docker` and is easy to include in a pipeline afterwards especially in i.e. `jenkins` multiple build nodes etc. (pita installing each node, i.e. `ansible`, `packer` + AWS, etc. maybe but still).

Answer (score 8):

You can give

```
RUN python -m unittest test_file_name.py
```

or

```
RUN python -m unittest tests/*
```

Comment: when I run `python -m unittest tests/*` I get:
`ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests/* ...`

Comment: @LucasRenan Make sure your root directory having the folder tests. From docker perspective it would be the location mapped as WORKDIR path you given.

Answer (score 5):

```
docker exec <name_container> python -m unittest discover
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either write another Dockerfile to change the entrypoint or you can override the entrypoint when you run your Dockerfile using the command

```
docker run --entrypoint
```

If your command needs arguments makes sure to pass them after the image name

```
docker run --entrypoint "pytest" image_name arg1 arg2 ...
```

Comment: (IMHO needing `docker run --entrypoint` gets kind of awkward.  In the Dockerfile in the original question, you could change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` to not need that option, `docker run image_name pytest arg1 ...`.  But that assumes the test files are in the image, which they wouldn't necessarily be.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a name of your running container,

you can execute a command on the running container with [`docker execute`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)

So let's say you want to run some tests through `pytest` specifying path to tests

on a container called/labeled "my_container":

```
docker exec my_container pytest ./tests/superstuff/
```

Note 2 things:

1. The `./` path is relative to your `WORKDIR`
2. If tests are generating some test/output files, they may have docker-root owner instead of the regular one, if that's not what you want, you can override it with the `--user` endpoint like so:
   `docker exec --user myuser:mygroup my_container pytest ./tests/superstuff/`

*At least on Linux(Ubuntu), you can also use `$(id -u):$(id -g)` - to get id&default group of the user running the command*

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer for anyone using Pycharm and trying to run unit tests inside Docker containers using Docker Compose.

If you have configured your service in your Compose file as an interpreter already, then you need to edit your Run/Debug configuration and just set the Docker Compose 'Command and options' to `exec` or `run`

[image]

Pycharm automatically inserts the other commands (from Pytest etc.) and runs this test inside your container!

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what is the scale of your application is and why do you want to use Docker for? Just because your application is running in Docker, doesn't mean you should run your tests in Docker too.

These are few options you could check from the lowest efforts to highest efforts.

#### Run your tests locally

```
$ python -m unittest tests/*
```

#### Use Python virtual environment

If you are thinking about not corrupting your local dependencies and just for that you want to use Docker, you could just use venv and run your tests there.

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ python3 -m unittest tests/*
```

Then you could just delete the directory or virtual environment

#### Use Jenkins or similar tools

This is ideal solution, provided you are writing a serious project. Jenkins (or similar tools) supports the dockerized running of jobs. Jenkins will create a docker container every time you want to run a job. 
You just specify what command you would like to give, it may be simple as in first option. Here's a link for [Jenkins with Docker support](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/).

Comment: -1 One of the advantages of docker is that I can re-create an environment from scratch using dependencies only supported by the docker image and not my development machine. E.g. I create a Docker with Ubuntu and run tests on it, whereas my machine is MacOSX which does not have the necessary dependencies versions.

Comment: While what you said is true, here we're not certainly discussing advantages of Docker. The projects in which people would use some core OS dependencies would be rare. As the OP has not mentioned that this is the case, then I think just creating docker every time you run test is over kill, IMHO. Again if that is the case, then I've given the Jenkins option which is better suitable.

Comment: @GaneshSatpute Main point was that ideally you should run tests on the target environment, running tests even in virtualenv is still not the same environment and things can and will differ and/or be affected differently. ***Especially*** if your containers shouldn't be coupled among each other.

Comment: @jave.web The question is asked for the unit test if I'm not mistaken. What you're talking about might be integration or functional tests. Even in that case, each of the service might be exposing some APIs and you can point the hosts in via configuration and still be able to run all the test in Jenkins like environment.

Comment: @GaneshSatpute my use case is writing AWS Lambda functions, which are small, but they allow you to use a Docker comtainer now. If testing can be done in the exact same environment that the function will run in then you'll find as many bugs as possible. This use case is going to become increasingly more important as everything moves to the cloud (or cloud-like setups)